# Which is better to format date using sql DATE_FORMAT() or SImpleDateFormat()?

Tags: java, mysql

Normally I format date using `SimpleDateFormat` in Java,
but I come to know that we can format date using SQL `DATE_FORMAT()` also.

So my concern is for performance point of view which is better to execute?

Comment: General rule: do us much in your query as you can

Comment: @Jhon Conde  but performance wise which is better??

Comment: FYI, the `SimpleDateFormat` class in Java is old legacy code, notoriously troublesome. Now supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes, specifically the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

Answer (score 2):

The performance of using one over the other will be negligible.

Instead, I would make the decision based on what will make my code (both SQL and Java) more maintainable, and what helps me respect the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

For instance, if you want to enforce a consistent date formatting across your whole application, what would make that easier?  Typically, centralizing that sort of logic is easier in Java code than in SQL queries.

Then again, it really depends on how you're setup.  For instance, if your database is setup as the back-end for more than one application, and you want consistent formatting behavior across all applications, it may be more convenient to centralize the formatting the logic in the database.

In short: it depends. But performance shouldn't be your primary concern in this case.